# Fetching data from Oracle database and store into an array using PHP

Tags: php, oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to fetch data from database, date-with-time(timestamp) and values(number) , and storing into an array using php.

here is my data in database as follows=

```
WD                                  DT

25-FEB-15 12.14.00.000000 AM    15.739993

25-FEB-15 12.23.00.000000 AM    13.698263   

25-FEB-15 12.43.00.000000 AM    13.214383
```

**fetch.php**

```
<?php
include("md.php");
$sql = "SELECT * from datatable";
$result =oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$r=oci_execute($result);
$arr = array();
$row=oci_num_rows($stid);
$arr[0]=array('wd','dt');

for($i=1; $i<($row+1); $i++)
{
    $arr[$i]= array(substr(oci_result($result, $i-1, "wd"),0,18),(float)oci_result($result,$i-1,"dt"));
    //$arr[$i]= array(substr(oci_result($result, $i-1, "wd"),0,18),(int)oci_result($result,$i-1,"dt"));

}
echo json_encode($arr);
//print_r($arr);
?>
```

$arr getting following output:
    [["WD"],["DT"]]

**Q1.**  Why am i not getting rest of data? where am i doing wrong?

but if i use

```
while($row = oci_fetch_row($stid)){

    $arr[] = $row;
}
```

if i use json_encode then =

```
[["25-FEB-15 12.14.00.000000 AM","15.739993"],["25-FEB-15 12.23.00.000000 AM","13.698263"],["25-FEB-15 12.43.00.000000 AM","13.214383"],....
```

if i use

```
while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC)){

  $arr[] = $row;
}
```

if i use json_encode then =

```
[{"WD":"25-FEB-15 12.14.00.000000 AM","DT":"15.739993"},{"WD":"25-FEB-15 12.23.00.000000 AM","DT":"13.698263"},........]
```

I want the output as follows=

```
[["25-FEB-15 12.14.00 AM",15.739993],["25-FEB-15 12.23.00 AM",13.698263],["25-FEB-15 12.43.00 AM",13.214383],....]
```

**Q2.**  How can i get it? 
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the data is being returned in an associative array you get the column name and the data for each column in each row returned to you. So this is being returned in `$row`

```
"WD" => "25-FEB-15 12.14.00.000000 AM", "DT" => "15.739993"
```

All you need to do is pick out the data from each row and ignore the Key like so :-

```
$arr = array();

while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC)){

  $arr[] = array($row['WD'] , $row['DT']);
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. now i figured it out how to get 'DT' value as my required output. thanks a lot